# At Most Two Distinct Members of A

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

The quantified predicate logic statement that describes at most two distinct members of **A**, where **A**, is some arbitrary set is:

$\forall$xyz( (Px $\land$ Py $\land$ Pz) $\Rightarrow$ (x=y $\lor$ x=z $\lor$ y=z) )

I can parse this quantified statement into three cases:

1. There are No Members of **A**
2. There is 1 Member of **A**
3. There are 2 Members of **A**

In case 2, x must equal y, then in turn for any z candidate, z is either equal to x, or to y, but x=y.
(So all three "or" statements are true.)

In case 3, x does not equal y, therefore for any z, z will either be equal to x, or z will be equal to y. (The first "or" fails, but the the other two are true.)

In case 1 I don't see how the quantified predicate statement guarantees that no membership can exist, i.e. there are non such members of A. If we don't choose any x, y, z then there are no such x,y, or z in **A** and the quantified statement "short circuits"? How do I interpret this or reason about it?

Comment: How does that quantified statement say anything at all about $\mathbf A$? Does $P$ have anything to do with $\mathbf A$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

P is a property that defines A.

For Case 1:
Objects x,y, and z exist in the Universe but since (Px∧Py∧Pz) was false, no candidate was held true for the property P that defines A thus their existence has no identity in A because they are not members of A; therefore, A is empty if the antecedent is false always -the consequent has no effect on defining membership in A. 
The consequent only ensures that IF there is a member in A for no matter how many candidates greater than or equal to one either they either all the same object or they are two distinct objects.

For Case 2:
(Px∧Py∧Pz) is true implying that it must be the case where at least one element is in A. The consequent checks to see what object in A it is- Since this is case 1 x=y and y=z and by transitivity of equivalence x=z. Therefore there is only one distinct member in A for case 1.

For Case 3:
(Px∧Py∧Pz) is true implying that it must be the case that two distinct elements are in A. The consequent checks to see what object(s) in A it is but in this case x $\neq$ y, so x=y check is irrelevant in the disjunctive statement so x and y are distinct and for any other candidate z checked it must be an alias for x or y.

Answer (score 1):

In the case 1 (no elements) the antecedent $(Px ∧ Py ∧ Pz)$ is  is false and the implication is true.

Comment: @MBPP I understand that a false antecedent can imply any consequent, but how does the conclusion state that x,y, or z doesn't exist in A?

Comment: @seeksUnderstanding, The formula guarantees that there are 0 **or** 1 **or** 2 elements in $A$.

Comment: Yes, I can clearly see that (x=y ∨ x=z ∨ y=z) guarantees that there are 0, or 1, or 2 elements in A, but I guess what I'm asking is how is any instantiation happening to the variables x, y, and z in the case where the antecedent is false, or is it because no instantiation of those variables occur that they all then represent the empty set or objects without Identity in A?

Comment: @MBPP I believe I understand now. P is a property that defines A. x,y, and z exist in the Universe but since (Px∧Py∧Pz) was false, no candidate was held the true for the property P that defines A thus their existence has no identity in A because they are not members of A; therefore, A is empty if the antecedent is false always (the consequent has really no effect on defining membership in A only ensures that IF there is a member in A for no matter how many candidates greater than or equal to one either they either all the same object or they are two distinct objects).

Comment: Where do you get "P is a property that defines A"? There is nothing like that in the question.

Comment: @bof, "The quantified predicate logic statement that describes at most two distinct members of $A$...".

Comment: @seeksUnderstanding, right.

Comment: In your question you **claim** that the displayed formula says something about A, but there is no A in the formula. Perhaps you have in mind some unstated connection between the set A and the predicate symbol P in the formula.

Comment: @bof, maybe the statement isn't very good, but the only reasonable interpretation is $x\in A\iff Px$.

Comment: @bof: most formulas in the three different books I'm reading don't actually specify the domain in the formula itself- the reader is left to assume that x,y, and z can only be in "some" set that the property P() defines. The set is arbitrary. I distinguished the arbitrary set as A, just to give it a name, which became useful later when I distinguished between the set A and the universal set of objects by the property P() that defines A.

Answer (score 0):

The statement is best read as (using inclusion in a set instead of a predicate; it doesn't really matter):

> If $x$, $y$, and $z$ are all in $A$, then there is some pair of them which are equal.

Clearly, this cannot hold for any set $A$ containing three distinct members - hence, we know that the above statement implies that $A$ has size no more than $2$. However, if $A$ has size of $2$ or less, it is equivalent to the pigeonhole principle, when we have $2$ "pigeonholes" and three elements (pigeons?) which we're trying to fit in the holes - and the statement says that it is impossible to assign $x$, $y$, and $z$ to members of $A$ without overlap.

We don't *really* want to break into cases for this, I don't think. What I just wrote is essentially a proof of "the statement implies $A$ has no more than two elements" followed by a proof of "$A$ having no more than two elements implies the statement" - whereas you were only handling the latter statement, which does not suffice to show the equivalence alone (since it doesn't prove that no set with $3$ elements, for instance, satisfies the condition).